# Modify Makefile to add GSL library

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, gsl

I have the following makefile and would like to also use the GSL library. Do you know how I should proceed?
I cannot find the right way to make my code compile for now.

```
INCLDIR := include
OBJDIR  := obj
SRCDIR  := src
BINDIR  := bin

CC      := g++
VPATH   :=
LDFLAGS := -L/home/path/gsl/lib
LIBRARY :=
CFLAGS  := -g -Wall -I $(INCLDIR)

#Source and object files (automatic)
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(subst $(SRCDIR)/,$(OBJDIR)/, $(subst .cpp,.o, $(SRCS)))

# Define here your main source files separated by spaces (without suffix!)
EXEC = main

#Phony = do not represent a file
#.PHONY: all
all : makedir $(EXEC)

# For multiple binaries
$(EXEC) : %: %.cpp $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BINDIR)/$@ $^

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

#Clean: delete every binaries and object files
.PHONY: clean
clean :
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*
    rm -rf $(BINDIR)/*
#Building folders (-p : no error if folder do not exist)
.PHONY: makedir
makedir :
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LDFLAGS` is missing `-lgsl`. Thus far you have only told the linker, where to search in addition to the default directories.

Comment: If that is a shared library the next question is likely to be "it links, but won't run".

Comment: well, run you program by first specifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Oh my god. Are you being serious. Fine, then copy libgsl.so into the systems search path like `/usr/local/lib`. I was just trying to help you get going.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that for shared libraries when you use `-L...` you also need `-Wl,-rpath=...`.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I added -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm on the LIBRARY line, but it still does not work as this library is saved under /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.4/lib. Would you know how I should modify the makefile to specify this?

Comment: -L/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.4/lib. Please don't forget to accept the answer 